# I want to develop rasa-nlu component to integrate with Google CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, google-natural-language

In the pipeline of Rasa NLU, I want to add my custom component which talks with google CLOUD NATURAL LANGUAGE API.
I want to know, is it a good idea to use google service instead of default engines available?
If yes, from where I can start building that component?
Also if I should consider to take care for a particular thing, I would like to know.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: any answers please?